# How to run test case in JUnit from command line ?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm trying to run a JUnit test case from command line using this command:

```
F:\>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit4.9b2.junit.SimpleTest
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.  Program will exit.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously you need junit on the classpath :-)

```
java -cp path/to/junit.jar:path/to/local/classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore \
         org.junit4.9b2.junit.SimpleTest
```

(replace the `:` with `;` on windows platforms)

Comment: I already did .. this is the value of CLASSPATH .;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;F:\junit\junit4.9b2;F:\junit\junit4.9b2\junit-4.9b2.jar;F:\junit\junit4.9b2\org\junit\samples

Comment: How can i specify execute one method of the testcase class?thanks

Comment: @janwen it doesn't seem like you can do that from the command line. But you should ask a separate question if you want to be sure. I know you can do it from Maven or Eclipse, but not from the CLI

Comment: thanks @SeanPatrickFloyd ,I am going to write shell script to do this.

Comment: @janwen for a single test case see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288107/run-single-test-from-a-junit-class-using-command-line