# Run single test from a JUnit class using command-line

Tags: java, unit-testing, command-line, junit

I am trying to find an approach that will allow me to run a single test from a JUnit class using only command-line and java.

I can run the whole set of tests from the class using the following:

```
java -cp .... org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.package.classname
```

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
java -cp .... org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.package.classname.method
```

or:

```
java -cp .... org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.package.classname#method
```

I noticed that there might be ways to do this using JUnit annotations, but I would prefer to not modify the source of my test classes by hand (attempting to automate this). I did also see that Maven might have a way to do this, but if possible I would like to avoid depending on Maven.

So I am wondering if there is any way to do this?

---

Key points I'm looking for:

- Ability to run a single test from a JUnit test class
- Command Line (using JUnit)
- Avoid modifying the test source
- Avoid using additional tools

Comment: Cool, another "Unix is my IDE" type enthusiast.  I like using an IDE for an editor (particularly with the vim plugin for NetBeans), but I agree that small sharp tools that last "forever", and can be assembled in arbitrary configurations, are often better than constantly relearning esoteric features of a continuing series of IDE brands and versions.  Good for you!

Comment: You said you wanted to avoid maven. For anyone who wants to do this using maven see look here, http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can make a custom, barebones JUnit runner fairly easily.  Here's one that will run a single test method in the form `com.package.TestClass#methodName`:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Request;
import org.junit.runner.Result;

public class SingleJUnitTestRunner {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String[] classAndMethod = args[0].split("#");
        Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(classAndMethod[0]),
                classAndMethod[1]);

        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
        System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

You can invoke it like this:

```
> java -cp path/to/testclasses:path/to/junit-4.8.2.jar SingleJUnitTestRunner 
    com.mycompany.product.MyTest#testB
```

After a quick look in the JUnit source I came to the same conclusion as you that JUnit does not support this natively.  This has never been a problem for me since IDEs all have custom JUnit integrations that allow you to run the test method under the cursor, among other actions.  I have never run JUnit tests from the command line directly; I have always let either the IDE or build tool (Ant, Maven) take care of it.  Especially since the default CLI entry point (JUnitCore) doesn't produce any result output other than a non-zero exit code on test failure(s).

NOTE:
for JUnit version >= 4.9 you need [hamcrest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core) library in classpath

Comment: Actually, I seem to remember getting a full stack trace in the log when an assertion in a test failed, as well as the (optional, when defined) message from each assertion describing the unrealized expectation.  Thanks for the work-around.

Answer (score 70):

I use Maven to build my project, and use SureFire maven plugin to run junit tests.
Provided you have this setup, then you could do:

```
mvn -Dtest=GreatTestClass#testMethod test
```

In this example, we just run a test method named "testMethod" within Class "GreatTestClass".

For more details, check out http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Answer (score 0):

We used IntelliJ, and spent quite a bit of time trying to figure it out too.

Basically, it involves 2 steps:

#### Step 1: Compile the Test Class

`% javac -cp .:"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/Contents/lib/*" SetTest.java`

#### Step 2: Run the Test

`% java -cp .:"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/Contents/lib/*" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore SetTest`

Comment: This runs every test in the class, not just one test.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works fine.

```
mvn -Dtest=SqsConsumerTest -DfailIfNoTests=false test
```