# Junit: changing sequence of test running

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, junit

I have a big mess with 100 tests in one class and running all of them by clicking "Test project (...). They run in a random order and I would like them to run in a specific order - from beginning to the end, the same order that I wrote them. In eclipse it's not a problem because eclipse just works like that, how to do it in netbeans?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit (due to answers): Tests order is required for the clearance of the log. They are independent.

Comment: How does order of tests matter? It is unlikely the IDE knows the order in which t you wrote the tests.

Comment: It's only for the clearance of xml log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tests needs to run in a specific order, something is wrong with your design.
2 test that needs to run one after another are 1 test. Consider this before searching for a solution.

check this https://blogs.oracle.com/mindless/entry/controlling_the_order_of_junit

Comment: No, they don't "need to". It's required because of the clearance of the xml log.

Answer (score 2):

Having tests depending on other tests 99.9% of the time a very bad idea. Unit tests should be independent from each other, as otherwise you might have a cascade of errors, or (even worse) one test failing because something another test did sometime before.

If you still want to go through this pain, you'll need to use a different unit testing framework (such as [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) - see dependsOnMethods) which supports test dependencies.

Junit doesn't support this feature because it's seen by many as a bad practice (for very good reasons).

Comment: My tests are independent. I need them in order because of clearance of xml log. Thank you for you answer, I consider using another environment, if there's no other way to solve it.

Comment: Doszi, that clearance **is** a dependency. Can you think of a way of breaking it so the tests don't need to be run in a specific sequence?

Answer (score 2):

The next JUnit release will [support ordering of test methods.](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/pull/386) The standard Maven Surefire Plugin [supports ordering of test methods already](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder).

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has good integration with ant build files. You could write a specific ant target that could execute each test in order.