# Is there any way to run an individual test method in groovy?

Tags: groovy, junit

I'd like to run an individual test method instead of the entire test class in Groovy on the cli - is this possible?

So instead of all the test methods in MyTestClass, I'd like to run just the testArbitrary method in MyTestClass.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How have you got everything set up?  Are you using some sort of build tool?

Comment: I'm using GroovyTestCase - I'm literally running "$ MyTestCase.groovy". I'm using groovy to tackle some projeceuler and sometimes I just want to run a single test method.

Comment: Could you use a static method?

Comment: As far as I remember, this style of test execution doesn't support executing a single method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intellij Idea you could create run configuration, that will start single test method. Command will be copied to output panel and will look like so

`com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit3 package.TestClass,testMethod`

Like this, you can create your custom JUnitStarter class as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9288513/1601606

Natively, there is no such class, but it's pretty simple to create it.