# Rerunning parametrized JUnit test with string array parameter fails

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

While using [parametrized JUnit tests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm) in Eclipse, I'm running into a problem when I want to rerun a single test. The tests themselves run fine, and while I *can* rerun the first test from the context menu, rerunning the second test:

[image]

fails with the following message:

> java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test[1: A2 --> [Ljava.lang.String;@1e4a7dd4]], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test[1: A2 --> Ljava.lang.String;@1e4a7dd4]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@6c3f5566

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is because JUnit doesn't 'like' my arrays; for some context: I'm using this to account for the fact that due to external circumstances, the code under test can produce one of two outcomes for a particular test case.

Here is some code to reproduce this:

```
package com.stackexchange.toolbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Tester {
    public Tester(String source, Object target) {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
    }

    private final String source;
    private final Object target;

    private static final Object[][] testCases = { { "A1", "B1" }, { "A2", new String[] { "B2", "C2" } } };

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0} --> {1}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() throws Exception {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(testCases));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        if (target instanceof String) {
            Assert.assertEquals(source.charAt(1), ((String)target).charAt(1));
        } else {
            for (String target : (String[])this.target) {
                Assert.assertEquals(source.charAt(1), target.charAt(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to fix this, perhaps with `List`s or variadic arguments? Most of the (100+) test cases are simple 'source', 'target' entries, and I'd like to keep the conciseness of `{ "A1", "B1" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation of JUnit4 ([at least you get the same error on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31637451/6505250)).

The simplest and straightforward solution would be to **migrate** from JUnit4 **to JUnit5**, which would also mean less code:

```
package com.stackexchange.toolbox;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

class Tester {
    
    private static final Object[][] testCases = { { "A1", "B1" }, { "A2", new String[] { "B2", "C2" } } };

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index}: {0} --> {1}")
    @MethodSource("provideArguments")
    void test(String source, Object target) {
        if (target instanceof String) {
            Assert.assertEquals(source.charAt(1), ((String)target).charAt(1));
        } else {
            for (String targetElement : (String[])target) {
                Assert.assertEquals(source.charAt(1), targetElement.charAt(1));
            }
        }
    }

    static Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments() throws Exception {
        return Arrays.stream(testCases).map(Arguments::of);
    }

}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I do miss one feature of the old setup: then it immediately became apparent how many test cases there were (and you could cancel the test and run a specific one). Right now, they're streamed and added one by one, it seems. The actual tests cost several seconds, so that is not ideal.

Comment: I see, but I can't think of a solution to this. Unfortunately, this is the same for [dynamic tests](https://www.baeldung.com/junit5-dynamic-tests). Maybe you can ask this as a separate question. As workaround for the total number you can add a third parameter, so you can do `name = "{index}/{2}: {0} --> {1}"`.