# Dynamic method calling of a JUNIT class

Tags: java, excel, dynamic, junit, testng

I am having a excel sheet having testcases name and some values related to it
eg: TestCase2 Value2, TestCase1 Value1.

I have a Junit class having test methods(TestCase1(), TestCase2()) as the same name I have in excel sheet
So when I run my Junit class I want the test methods to execute serially the way they are mentioned in excel file as in this case testcase2 should execute before testcase1.

Comment: So you want to build a TestSuite of tests using names based on some input....

Comment: Why are you using an excel sheet for this? You want the tests to be usable by some user? If that is the case you could think of FitNesse.

Comment: Yes Peter , Test case method names will be coming from excel sheet and they should execute serially the way they are mentioned

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:
Use Excel to construct and launch command lines, with Excel/windows capabilities (VBscript, ...).**

To launch junit tests:

java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]

see that:
[How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Note that you can launch a class, not a particular method.

For particular method, see that: [Run single test from a JUnit class using command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288107/run-single-test-from-a-junit-class-using-command-line)

For the order of methods, see below.

But, how you get and exploit results is another thing.

**Method 2 (prefered):** Control everything from Java:

Read excel file, with proper library:

[How to read and write excel file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java)

or, change it to csv, or OpenOffice (odf), and read with other libraries.

Iterate, and launch each method by its name by reflexivity:

*getMethod* and *Invoke*.

See that: [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

**Order of tests:**

Set this before the class:

*@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)*

Then your tests will be executed in lexical order

Hope it helps !