# How to run spock test from command line?

Tags: groovy, command-line, spock

I have checked this link:

https://gist.github.com/ysb33r/5825457

It seems like that it can be run like this:

```
groovyc *.groovy

java -cp ~/.grapes/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.4.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/junit-4.11.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:.org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ExampleSpec
```

And I have added all third part jars to CLASSPATH,so all imports from these libs found.But all my own classes can't be found,and error message like this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
LoginTest.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class com.vsi.icareos.client.home.HomePage
@ line 11, column 1.
import com.vsi.icareos.client.home.HomePage
^

LoginTest.groovy: 22: unable to resolve class LoginByPwdPage 
@ line 22, column 2.
LoginByPwdPage loginPage
^

LoginTest.groovy: 35: unable to resolve class LoginByPwdPage 
     @ line 35, column 13.
       loginPage=new LoginByPwdPage(browser,Consts.PAGE_ID)
          ^
3 errors
```

I guess that the option like:--sourcepath is needed,but I found this command option deprecated,so How to slove this problem?

Comment: Are you using any form of build tool?  It's a bit of work to start with, but saves you from all this messing about in the long run.  I use Gradle, but there's also Maven and Ant

Comment: @tim_yates,not yet,right now,I just want to run a single specification.

Comment: If you were using gradle, this can be done by `gradle test --tests your.packages.SomeSpecificSpec`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run the tests described in the gist, but with modification of the `groovyc` to add the `-cp` flag with spock jar to it, also if you have the sources in sub-directories you should use `**/*.groovy` instead of `*.groovy`

Looking at the way you run the `java` command, it seams to be missing a space between `.` and `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`

So instead of

```
java -cp ~/.grapes/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.4.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/junit-4.11.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:.org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ExampleSpec
```

I should be

```
java -cp ~/.grapes/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.4.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/junit-4.11.jar:$GROOVY_HOME/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ExampleSpec
```

Please note the space in the second.
The `.` is the current directory added to the classpath

hope this helps

Comment: for spock 2.0, juit5 should be used to execution unit tests https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-execution