# Run single junit test with cli

Tags: java, junit, command-line-interface

I need to run a single test case run through the cli. I created a runner class

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String ... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String[] classAndMethod = args[0].split("#");
        Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(classAndMethod[0]),
                classAndMethod[1]);
        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
        System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

using this answer
[Run single test from a JUnit class using command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288107/run-single-test-from-a-junit-class-using-command-line?rq=1).

I downloaded from github a project (https://github.com/apache/incubator-dubbo) on which I want to run the single method, I positioned myself from terminal on the directory containing the Runner class I created and I launched the following command:

```
java -cp /path/incubator-dubbo/dubbo-cluster /usr/share/java/junit4-4.12.jar /pathClassRunner/src/com/company/Runner org.apache.dubbo.rpc.cluster.StickyTest#testHeartbeat
```

but I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class pathClassRunner.src.com.company.Runner
```

can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: If the first and second parameter are both classpaths, then maybe: `/path/incubator-dubbo/dubbo-cluster;/usr/share/java/junit4-4.12.jar`

Comment: I tried to launch the following command:
 sudo java -cp /pathTo/incubator-dubbo/;/usr/share/java/junit-4.8.2.jar pathToClassRunner/src/com/company/Runner org.apache.dubbo.rpc.cluster.StickyTest#testHeartbeat

but I got a: bash: /usr/share/java/junit-4.8.2.jar: Permission denied

Comment: I'm no posix expert, but my guess it it's not executable or your user doesn't have access to it. On posix you also have to use `:` not `;` between items in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The command expects you to include any paths in the `classpath` with NO spaces. A space means that the arguments for the `classpath` has ended. It there is a space in one of your paths you may include double quotes:

```
java -cp path1:path2:path3 classname argument
java -cp "path1:path2:path3" classname argument
```

If a path starts with `/` it's a full path. If not it's relative to where you run your command. The `classname` must be the name of the class, not the file, so that means no `.class`. If your `class` specifies any `package`, then the `classname` is required to contain the `package` name too, and the path is to the **root** of the `package`, not the `class` itself.

Check that your user has proper access to the files, then try:

```
java -cp /path/incubator-dubbo/dubbo-cluster:/usr/share/java/junit4-4.12.jar:/pathClassRunner/src/com/company Runner org.apache.dubbo.rpc.cluster.StickyTest#testHeartbeat
```

I'm assuming your `Runner` is in the default package. In case it's in the com.company package, you'll want to run this instead:

```
java -cp /path/incubator-dubbo/dubbo-cluster:/usr/share/java/junit4-4.12.jar:/pathClassRunner/src com.company.Runner org.apache.dubbo.rpc.cluster.StickyTest#testHeartbeat
```

Another assumption is that your `Runner.class` is in your `/pathClassRunner/src...` directory.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried to execute the command like you told me to
java -cp Desktop/roba/incubator-dubbo/dubbo-cluster/:/usr/share/java/junit4-4.12.jar: Desktop/roba/script/progetti/customJUnit/src/com/company/Runner org.apache.dubbo.rpc.cluster.StickyTest#testHeartbeat
but the result of the terminal is:
Error: Could not find or load main class Desktop.roba.script.progetti.customJUnit.src.com.company.Main.java
the .class file is in the directory 
/home/broke31/Desktop/desktop/wardrobe/script/projects/customJUnit/out/production/customJUnit/com

Comment: I don't understand why it would say anything ending in `Main.java` when you haven't specified that in your command.

Comment: Sorry, I renamed the "Main" class to "Runner", copy and paste error.

Comment: You need to specify the class path to your class. Not to your java file. If it's in `/home/broke31/Desktop/desktop/wardrobe/script/projects/customJUnit/out/production/customJUnit/com` then that's what you need to use. Did you put your class in a package?